# Is there a way to pick out specific elements from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I'm trying to read input from three separate files, and the user specifies which file to read. Each line in each file contains info about a temperature reading: a latitude, a longitude, the year, the month, the max temp, the min temp, and the average temp. So each line looks something like this:

```
39.95 41.1667 2002 04 -9999 -9999 420
```

Each temperature will also be divided by 10 to get the actual temperature in Celsius. If the temperature is -9999, it will not be read. Also, each item is added to an ArrayList that I have:

```
ArrayList<TempRead> t = new ArrayList();
```

I also have a TempRead class that looks like this:

```
public class TempRead {
private double latitude = -100;
private double longitude = -180;
private int year = 0;
private int month = 0;
private double maxTemp = -9999;
private double minTemp = -9999;
private double avgTemp = -9999;

public TempRead(){}

public TempRead(double latitude, double longitude, int year, int month, double maxTemp, double minTemp, double avgTemp){
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.maxTemp = maxTemp;
    this.minTemp = minTemp;
    this.avgTemp = avgTemp;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}

public int getMonth(){
    return month;

}

public int getYear(){
    return year;
}

public double getMaxTemp(){
    return maxTemp;
}

public double getMinTemp(){
    return minTemp;
}

public double avgTemp(){
    return avgTemp;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return latitude + " " + longitude + " " + year + " " + month + " " + maxTemp + " " + minTemp + " " + avgTemp + " ";
}
```

The problem I'm having right now is that I'm not exactly sure how to get the temperature elements of the ArrayList. I've done something like this:

```
System.out.println(t.get(0));
```

And it shows that each line is in fact being added to the ArrayList, as it prints out the first line in the file. But I have to calculate averages, and max and mins. Is there a way that I can pick out the last three values of the ArrayList specifically so that I can do these calculations?

EDIT: Here is what I have in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<TempRead> t = new ArrayList();
    readFile(t);
    avgAllTemps(t);
}

public static void readFile(ArrayList<TempRead>t){
        try{
        String userFileName;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
        userFileName = in.next();
        System.out.println();

        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(userFileName));

        while(file.hasNext()){
            t.add(new TempRead(file.nextDouble(), file.nextDouble(), file.nextInt(), file.nextInt(), file.nextDouble(), file.nextDouble(), file.nextDouble()));
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void avgTemps(ArrayList<TempRead>t){
    double totalMinTemp = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    for (TempRead entry : t) {
        if (entry.getMinTemp() != -9999) {
            totalMinTemp += entry.getMinTemp();
            count++;
        }
        double avgMinTemp = totalMinTemp / count;
        System.out.println("Avg of min temps in arraylist: " + avgMinTemp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question really? How to get values or how to do the calculations? t.get(0) = TempRead, so t.get(0).getMinTemp() = minTemp value

Comment: Well yes, use `t.size()` to find out how many there are, then use `t.get(size - 3)`, `t.get(size - 2)`, `t.get(size - 1)` - making sure you handle the case where there are fewer than 3 elements. Although I don't see how taking just the last three readings would actually help you...

Comment: Just to clarify: You `ArrayList` contains objects of the type `TempRead` which itself might contain other properties. So "the last three values of the ArrayList" doesn't make sense in the way you use it. `t.get(0)` will return you a `TempRead` object and you can simply call the methods of that object to access its properties: `t.get(0).getMinTemp()` for example.

Comment: Use `line.split(" ")` to get array of fields. Beware of additional spaces and empty lines. You can also have a look at http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ - create a file reader which will divide each line into parts, each part with a specific meaning in your case. You just need to use SPACE as delimiter.

Comment: @Stefan I wasn't asking about how to do calculations, I can definitely do those myself. I was just wondering if there was a way to pick out specific pieces of info, like a specific max temp from a specific line. So yes, doing t.get(0).getMinTemp() will get me the min temp specifically from the first line. But what if the file has, let's say 50 lines? I would need to write a for loop for that, right?

Comment: `while(maxTemp != -9999)` may cause an infinite loop, and using `t.stream()[...]` inside of the loops may be a bad idea.  Are you trying to calculate the average maximum of all of the data?

Comment: @phflack well I was just trying different things. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is let the user pick a task from a menu, like average of all temps, the highest and lowest temps, avg of all temps, etc. I was just trying different things so that I could have a better understanding of what needed to be done next

Comment: @ANewProgrammer added a bit for finding the average of all of the elements

Comment: @phflack that works! But I still can't output the correct thing. I tried to output just the average, and it outputs the average, but it does it a hundred or so times because that's how many lines are in my txt file. The same thing happens when I try to make my menu; I can get it to output just the menu, but when I include something like System.out.println("do this thing"); it will output that print statement a hundred or so times because that's how many lines are in my txt file

Comment: @ANewProgrammer Try removing the loop causing the issue.  The two methods of doing it in my answer are stand-alone ways of calculating the average, and the print/return statement should be right after

Comment: @phflack the only other loop I have is the while loop that adds everything to the arraylist. Is there another way for me to read each line from the file and add it to the arraylist then?

Comment: @ANewProgrammer The code you have in your post is out of date.  If you only have one loop to read data and it does not process or output the data, then you shouldn't be having this issue.  It may help to split the different parts into distinct methods.  One method would read the data and return the list, while the others would be for processing

Comment: @phflack I updated the main code above. I just tried splitting it all into different methods, but I'm still getting the hundred or so lines, and I'm not understanding why. Btw, I genuinely appreciate your help. It's definitely helped out a lot. This has been the hardest concept for me to understand so far

Comment: @ANewProgrammer You have `for([...]){if([...]){[...]} double avgMinTemp = [...]; System.out.println([...]);}`.  Try moving those two statements to after the loop: `for([...]){if([...]){[...]}} double avgMinTemp = [...]; System.out.println([...]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for temperature, you should not be looking for the last 3 elements of the ArrayList, instead look for data inside of each element in the ArrayList

To get the temperatures from the first entry:

```
TempRead entry = t.get(0);
double maxTemp = entry.getMaxTemp();
double minTemp = entry.getMinTemp();
double avgTemp = entry.avgTemp();
//do stuff
```

If you need every entry, use a loop:

```
for(TempRead entry : t)
{
    double maxTemp = entry.getMaxTemp();
    double minTemp = entry.getMinTemp();
    double avgTemp = entry.avgTemp();
    //do stuff
}
```

---

To do tasks like averaging all of the minTemp values

```
double totalMinTemp = 0.0;
int count = 0;
for(TempRead entry : t)
    if(entry.getMinTemp() != -9999)
    {
        avgMinTemp += entry.getMinTemp();
        count++;
    }
double avgMinTemp = totalMinTemp / count;
```

Or using streams (thanks @JeroenSteenbeeke)

```
double avgMinTemp = t.stream().filter(t -> t.getMinTemp() != -9999).collect(Collectors.averaging(TempRead::getMaxTemp‌​));
```

Comment: And if you're using Java 8, you can also use Streams with your List. Calculate the average of you maximum temperatures? `double averageMaxTemp = t.stream().collect(Collectors.averaging(TempRead::getMaxTemp));`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke thanks for that! Along with phflack 's response, I'm getting the desired outcomes. But it seems to be printing in an infinite loop now. I'm not sure what it is that's causing it. I edited my post to reflect the changes I've made within my main code

Answer (score 0):

You can use Iterator on arraylist as:

```
Iterator itr=t.iterator(); 
  while(itr.hasNext()){  //For each list element
    TempRead tr=(TempRead)itr.next(); //To access values of each list element as tr.maxTemp etc  
  }
```

Comment: `tr.maxTemp` is private

Comment: iterator instead of index is less efficient; ArrayList is an indexed collection